# Physical Spatial frequencies from fft2 on astronomical images

Tags: python, numpy, fft

Assuming I have an astronomical image which is 512x512 pixels with a pixel scale of 6 arcminutes. I want to compute the spatial frequencies kx, ky in physical units (arcmin^{-1}) and plot the 2D power spectrum as a function of them. This is what I have done

```
import numpy as np

PIXEL_SCALE = 6.0 # arcmin

N_PIXELS = 512
y, x = np.mgrid[0:N_PIXELS * PIXEL_SCALE:PIXEL_SCALE, \
   0:N_PIXELS * PIXEL_SCALE:PIXEL_SCALE]

k = 0.5
z = np.sin(2.0 * np.pi * k * y)

z_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(z)))

# FREQUENCIES
ky_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(y.shape[0], PIXEL_SCALE)) 
kx_fft = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[1], PIXEL_SCALE))
```

Is this correct ? If i wanted them is units of radians/arcmin I suppose I also need to multiply by 2.0 * np.pi

Comment: 1. Why do you use the inverse FFT (`ifft2`) to compute the spectrum? 2. `(i)fftshift` should almost certainly not be applied to the spatial-domain data.

Comment: 1) using ifft2 instead fft2 will only change the amplitude of the 2D spectral density so it really doesn't matter in this case. 2) I not sure why fftshift should not be applied in this case. I simply shift the power spectrum at the centre of the image. The kx_fft, ky_fft are symmetric with respect to 0.

Comment: 1) Yep. It's fine if you know what you are doing, although there is no actual reason to. :) 2) I was referring to the particular case of `np.fft.ifftshift(z)`. The other uses of `fftshift` seem to be fine.